# C# Unit test not waiting for app to close before proceeding to next unit test class

Tags: c#, unit-testing

Using MSTest I have six unit test classes. I need an app (SolidWorks) to start from scratch for each test. No problem, I have the following in my unit test class to start and stop SolidWorks before the class starts and after the class finishes:

```
    [ClassInitialize()]
    public static void MyClassInitialize(TestContext testContext)
    {
        var progId = "SldWorks.Application";
        var progType = System.Type.GetTypeFromProgID(progId);
        app = System.Activator.CreateInstance(progType) as ISldWorks;
        app.Visible = true;

        DocumentSpecification documentSpecification;
        documentSpecification = (DocumentSpecification)app.GetOpenDocSpec(fullFilePath);
        documentSpecification.DocumentType = (int)swDocumentTypes_e.swDocPART;
        var result = app.OpenDoc7(documentSpecification);
        if (result == null)
        {
            throw new Exception("Couldn't load SOlidworks test file.");
        }
    }


    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void MyClassCleanup()
    {
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.CloseAllDocuments(true);
            app.ExitApp();
        }
    }
```

My problem is that when UnitTestClass1 gets finished UnitTestClass2 starts before SolidWorks is finished closing. UnitTestClass2 seems to be grabbing the SolidWorks process that was started in UnitTestClass1. I tried adding Thread.Sleep:

```
    [ClassCleanup()]
    public static void MyClassCleanup()
    {
        if (app != null)
        {
            app.CloseAllDocuments(true);
            app.ExitApp();
            Thread.Sleep(5000);
        }
    }
```

That didn't seem to work.

I tried a while loop to wait for Solidworks to close and that seems to hang.

If I run each unit test class one by one they all run fine and pass. Run as a group some of them fail because they are testing against the wrong environment (the file from the last test is still open).

How to make sure the next unit test doesn't run before the app is closed from the last unit test?

The behavior I want is for SolidWorks to run at the beginning of the class, run all the tests in the class and then for SolidWorks to close at the end of the class. I want this to happen for each class.

Comment: What testing library is this? MSTest? Nunit? Xunit? Something else?

Comment: If this is MSTest, ClassInitialize/Cleanup is called once for ALL tests in the class, TestInitialize/Cleanup is called for each test.

Comment: @dugas - This is MSTest. I want Solidworks to load at the beginning of the class initialization, run ALL tests in that class and then close SolidWorks at the end of the class. I want that to happen for each class.

Comment: @EricSnyder, you should edit your post to reflect that.

Comment: @EricSnyder - I don't think ClassCleanup is guaranteed to be triggered immediately.

Comment: @dugas - Uggg... That's really going to slow down the tests. SolidWorks takes a long time to open. I actually have quite a few more tests written than just this one set of six classes.

Comment: These aren't unit tests. Unit tests shouldn't rely on external systems, shouldn't have any sort of temporal coupling with other tests, and should be completely atomic. These are integration tests.